# How to create a variable that will hold all data in a text file without using a has.next method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a particular spot counting from position 0 where a word occurs. Heres what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class SearchFile {  
    public static void main ( String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;


        File text = new File ( "TEXT.txt" ); //Makes new object of File Class called text and creates     a text document called whatever they want
        Scanner reader = new Scanner ( text ); //makes object of Scanner class called reader to read from the text file
        Scanner finder = new Scanner ( System.in ); //makes object of Scanner class called finder to store input

        System.out.print ( "Please enter a file name: ");
        String name = finder.nextLine();
        System.out.print ( "Please enter a word you want me to search for: " );
        String check = finder.nextLine();

        while ( reader.hasNextLine()){
            String word = reader.next() + " ";
            if ( word.equalsIgnoreCase ( check )){
               System.out.println ( "Searching in file name: " + name + "...\nThe word " + check + " occurs " + count + " time in the text file." );
                count++;  
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            int occurs = word.indexOf(check);
            System.out.println ( "The word " + check + " occurs first at index " + occurs + ".");    
        }
        if ( count == 0 ){
            System.out.println ( "Sorry! Unable to find word" );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my "`word`" only has a value while in the loop. Thus making it impossible for me to use it outside the loop. Can anyone help me? Maybe give me something new I haven't tried yet?

Comment: Declare `word` before the loop?

Comment: Yes ofc but as what? If I just declare with nothing, it will remain nothing and still only have a value during the while loop

Comment: Right, just like you declare `count` outside the loop, put `word` there on the line after it.  This is called "scope" btw, look that word up.

Comment: So I tried that but I had to get rid of the String in front of word in the while loop to be able to declare it after the count. Even so, after running a test to check if word now had the same values as inside the loop I got blanks.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As I may have mentioned earlier, I'm simply trying to be able to use indexOf in order to get where a word I want to check occurs in the text file. In order to be able to do this I have to be able to have a value for the data in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = reader.next() + " ";
```

You have declared "`word`" within your while block. So, the system knows this variable only when it is inside the loop and once it is outside the loop it forgets about it. If you want to use the variable outside the loop, you should declare it outside. I understand that you tried it once. Now, why word is having the same values outside the loop even after this? "`word`" takes the value from the file, that reader gives through `reader.next()`. So, once you are outside the loop, it will still be having the last value `reader.next()` had provided. If you want to see the values of word, just give a print statement immediately after assigning the value to it.

```
   String word="";
   while ( reader.hasNextLine()){
     word = reader.next() + " ";
     System.out.println("Word:"+word);

          |
          |
          |

     }
```

Note: If you want the `word` variable to hold the whole words of the file, then do this.

`word=word+reader.next();`

Comment: If I declare word outside the loop, what value will it have? Inside the loop it has the values of the text file, but outside it has nothing. So how do I get word outside the loop while retaining the same values as inside the loop?

Comment: When you say declare- it means telling this- "String word;" But if you assign it a value during declaration like this-  " String word=""; ", then it tells the compiler that word is a String object which points to a null value. In every iteration of the loop, you can see different values assigned to the word variable. Once you come out of the loop, the last assigned value will remain. If you want the whole of the file, do this- word=word+reader.next();

Comment: I understand what you are saying but if I don't assign it a value I will get an error, and if I do declare it and use the while loop to get the whole of the file, then during my if statement in the while loop, will I not get a blank since it will be referring back to when I assigned "String word". I've tried it and I cant seem to pinpoint the reason why, it just skips across that if statement in the while loop and deduced that the word.equalsIgnoreCase(check) no longer works correctly because the "word" now has a different value?

Comment: You should declare it and should assign a value, say null ( `""` ).  Before you issue your `if` statement, there is another assignment to `word`, right? So, it cannot be blank, unless your file has blank values. Please do a debug with print statements and may be a debugger and come back if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file using the `Files` class. This code will find the *first occurrence in every line*:

```
Path path = Paths.get("path");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
int found = -1;
for (String line : lines)
    found = line.indexOf("word");
```

Don't forget to replace the path and the search word.

If you want to find the *first occurrence in the whole file*, use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines)
    sb.append(line);
found = sb.toString().indexOf("word");
```

Or find the *first occurrence in every line* with respect to all lines before it:

```
int loc = 0;
for (String line : lines) {
    if (line.indexOf("word") != -1);
        found = loc + line.indexOf("word");
    loc += line.length();
}
```

You can also use a `Pattern`-`Matcher` combination for this and it will be easier if you want to find *all* occurrences of the word.